# How to tell Firefox to give up on external content

Tags: firefox

Sometimes you open pages which have some small external content like a tracking system, stats counter and the like, and sometimes these services are slow or even not available. Still, firefox waits for a very long period of time during which the page load is not complete. Is there a wait to set a time limit after which it gives up and ends the page load no matter what?

Comment: doesn't hitting the `Stop` button on the taskbar in Firefox stop the current page load at whatever point it has reached? OK, it's a manual action, which is why this is a comment.

Comment: yes it does, but I'm looking for a configurable timeout

Answer (score 2):

I use NoScript and Adblock Plus to cut out the tracking behavior.  Also, if you use a cookie manager (if you accept cookies), you have more control over the tracking.

Quickly looking at the about:config panel, I didn't see anything on page loading timeouts, but it was a ***fast*** look.

---

Another couple of extensions to look at, would be the [DownForEveryoneOrJustMe](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/down-for-everyone-or-just-me/) search plugin.  (Just put the domain into the search box and search, will bring up the test site which tells you if it is just your system or the whole site)

The other one to look at, might be [ImgLikeOpera](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imglikeopera/).  I haven't used it for a while, but you can whitelist or temp whitelist or blacklist images with it.  Don't know how it works nowadays.  I last used it with versions before 3.5.x, as I remember.

Comment: NoScript and Adblock deal with content you want to permanently avoid, my problem is with resources that are *temporarily* down or slow.

Answer (score 0):

Just open about:config (by typing it in your address bar) and search for "timeout", decrease values.